# MySQL XDEV Nodejs Driver not returning empty resultset

Tags: mysql, node.js, resultset, connector, mysql-8.0

i'm calling a stored procedure mysql using xdev nodejs driver. The stored procedure returns multiple resultset. When trying nextresultset, i'm getting only the non-empty resultset. So this messes with the resultant data index.

Comment: Can you post a reproducible example? The stored procedure itself and table content if any table is involved. The feature is nicely covered by the [test suite](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-nodejs/blob/master/test/functional/sql.js#L186-L391) but you might be running into some weird corner case.

Disclaimer: I'm the lead dev of the X DevAPI connector for Node.js

Comment: Try to parse a stored procedure like this
DELIMITER //
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS debug_for_mysql;
//
create procedure debug_for_mysql()
begin
select * from users limit 2;
 select * from users where 1 = 0;
select * from users limit 1;
end
//

Comment: If you try to parse result in node using next result, you will not be getting proper output. if you execute the same workbench u can see 3 results

Comment: I don't see anything special with with that procedure. Can you provide the code snippet for actually processing the result set? You can see a similar working example [here](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-nodejs/blob/master/test/functional/sql.js#L222-L237).

Comment: The difference  is one of the result will be  empty. In your multi procedure, put a where condition 1=0 in the second one and see what happens. basically u r making the second resultset as 0 rows.

Comment: Oh, I see, I wasn't really understanding the problem was related to empty result-sets. This looks like a bug. So maybe you can submit a report on https://bugs.mysql.com/ using the `Connector for Node.js` category.

Comment: Thank you. Will submit the bug. Basically i was looking for toJson functionality in RowResult.js While trying to write on my own, i encountered this. It would be  great if nodejs can provide json based result.

Comment: It sort of does already. There's a `toArray()` method and JavaScript arrays are valid JSON. See my answer below :)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can understand, the problem is that `nextResult()` returns `false` when there are no items in the following result set.

This is an issue in a way that it breaks the following iterator pattern

```
const res = await session.sql('call proc_with_multiple_and_some_empty_result_sets()').execute()

do {
  // do something
} while (res.nextResult())
```

and does not allow to easily consume the entire result set.

There are workarounds for this, such as using the `toArray()` method and iterate over the plain data:

```
res.toArray().forEach(item => {
  // do something
})
```

However, this is a bug, and maybe you can submit a report on https://bugs.mysql.com/ under the `Connector for Node.js` category.

Disclaimer: I'm the lead dev of the MySQL X DevAPI Connector for Node.js